# How to athorization in passport nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

What i wonder is how to athorization by passport in nodejs

i've tried to use this req.isAuthenticated(), but it alway works `false` even if browser has cookie session, and logined

```
req.isAuthenticated()
```

I config passport.ts like this

```
import { Request } from 'express';
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = (userRepository: any) => {

    passport.serializeUser((user: any, done: any) => {
        console.log("serializeUser good");
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((user: any, done: any) => {
        console.log("deserializeUser good");
        console.log("deserializeUser user : ", user);
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'id',
        passwordField: 'pw',
        session: true,
        passReqToCallback: false,
    }, async (id: any, pw: any, done: any) => {

        const result = await userRepository.findOne({
            where: {
                userId: id
            }
        });

        if (!result) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'it dont exist pw or id' });
        }
        return done(null, { userId: result.userId });
    }))
}
```

and then, i've used passport.ts like this

```
const passportConfig = require('./passport');
passportConfig(userRepository); // userRepository is entity typeorm 

    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3001/Login'
    }), (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/');
    })
```

as i said, the problem is req.isAuthenticated(), but it alway works false

how can i use to athorization by passport libary?

Comment: is there an reason why you put everywhere type `any`

Comment: i am not Familiar typescript and didn't know type sir..

Comment: i see. You dont even need to put `any` because the callback usually have already some types defined by the library creator, usually. If not, you will need to install it `npm install --save @types/passport`

Comment: if i don't define type in callback i can see ide error :(

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: you mean like if i can type : any , it is gonna be okay? right? not? 

my english is not as good sorry :(

Comment: yes you can put everywhere `any`, but typescript would be pretty useless then, atleast my opinion